# Why am I getting a file not found exception here?

Tags: java, string, comparison

This is driving me nuts!
I used both concatenation and format and while the strings produced match the correct paths, the loop throws exceptions from the get go.

what's going on?

```
ImageIcon thisWorks= new ImageIcon(testview.class.getResource("/led_images/"+1+"_off.png"));
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        String on = String.format("/led_images/%d_on.png",i);
        String off = String.format("/led_images/%d_off.png",i);


    ledIcons.put( i+"_off", new ImageIcon(testview.class.getResource(off)));
    ledIcons.put( i+"_on", new ImageIcon(testview.class.getResource(on)));
    }
```

Edit:
am I using Map incorrectly?
It's a `Map<String,ImageIcon>` one.

Edit2:
Yeah I guess I'm using the map incorrectly.

I have it declared like this:

```
public Map< String, ImageIcon> ledIcons;
```

It's a null value inside the loop.
So I guess it's not like c++ then?

Edit3:
Yeah, nevermind this question, I didn't initialize the field properly, my apologies.

Comment: So when does it throw an exception, did you surround with try catch block ? Did you debug this code line by line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize the field:

```
public Map< String, ImageIcon> ledIcons = new HashMap< String, ImageIcon>();
```

Comment: indeed that fixed it. Damn other language habits.

Answer (score 3):

If `thisWorks` works, then obviously `"/led_images/1_off.png"` exists. If you get exceptions for the images in the loop, then perhaps one of

```
/led_images/2_off.png
/led_images/2_off.png
/led_images/3_off.png
...
/led_images/10_off.png

/led_images/1_on.png
/led_images/2_on.png
/led_images/3_on.png
...
/led_images/10_on.png
```

are missing.

> ***Edit: am I using Map incorrectly? It's a Map one.***

No, that looks fine to me. (Unless you have a problem with the retrieval later on.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the leading slash is the problem; you probably want a relative path.  See the docs:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

Comment: Print out the Strings; I'll bet the path is invalid.  Catch the exception and print the stack trace.